# Python: Plots closed as soon function finishes

Tags: python, matplotlib, parallel-processing

I have a function which plots with the help of `matplotlib.pyplot` some diagrams. The function is run several times in parallel by

`from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(runConfig)(cnt) for cnt in config)`

As soon as all instances have finished, the plots get closed.

How can I keep them alive?

Comment: Try `plt.show(block=True)`

Comment: @DavidG. For reference, that would prevent the instances from finishing until the plots were closed, but I do not see this as being a problem for OP unless more information is provided.

Comment: Another option is to save the plots to a file and view them that way.

Comment: I added an alternative answer to the other question that may be more reliable for older versions of mpl.